# Best way to avoid the submit due to a refresh of the page

Tags: php, html, forms

I think that this problem occurs often on a web application development. But I'll try to explain in details my problem.

I'd like to know how to correct this behavior, for example, when I have a block of code like this :

```
<?
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        ... operation on database, like to insert $_POST['name'] in a table ...
        echo "Operation Done";
        die();
    }

?>

<form action='page.php' method='post' name="myForm">
    <input type="text" maxlength="50" name="name" class="input400" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

When the form gets submitted, the data get inserted into the database, and the message *Operation Done* is produced. Then, if I refreshed the page, the data would get inserted into the database again.

How this problem can be avoided? Any suggestion will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Don't show the response after your create action; redirect to another page after the action completes instead. If someone refreshes, they're refreshing the GET requested page you redirected to.

```
// submit
// set success flash message (you are using a framework, right?)
header('Location: /path/to/record');
exit;
```

Comment: This is what you should always do. There's even a wiki page for this pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: This is a good solution, and its easy to implement by using some Frameworks (like Struts2 or JSF, I already done it in the past). In fact I don't know the best sstrategy on php :)

Comment: Simple, obvious, elegant etc =)

Comment: Nice strategy! Of course I've to implement all my form with new page as redirect (damn...)! Thanks :)

Comment: P.S. is it possible pass trought the header function some variables in POST? Or only trought GET?

Comment: I found the pattern MVC a bit embarrassing programming on PHP :) But yes, I lost this PRG step...

Comment: You misunderstand my last question I think. No matter, I'll open a new topic right now! Thanks for all suggestions ;)

Answer (score 27):

Set a random number in a session when the form is displayed, and also put that number in a hidden field.  If the posted number and the session number match, delete the session, run the query; if they don't, redisplay the form, and generate a new session number.  This is the basic idea of XSRF tokens, you can read more about them, and their uses for security here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Here is an example:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['formid']) && isset($_SESSION['formid']) && $_POST["formid"] == $_SESSION["formid"])
{
    $_SESSION["formid"] = '';
    echo 'Process form';
}
else
{
    $_SESSION["formid"] = md5(rand(0,10000000));
?>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["formid"]); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Aditional if session expires: 
if(!empty($_SESSION["formid"]) && $_POST["formid"] == $_SESSION["formid"])

Comment: Thanks Joefay, you're right I should definitely check that the `formid` still exists in the session before using it.  I've updated my answer

Comment: We ran into the strange case that `$_POST['form']` and `$_SESSION['form']` become an empty string. So `isset(...)` returns true and the condition is full-filled. We have to also test for `!is_null($_SESSION["formid"])`.

Comment: The user will still be getting a browser warning, right? Is there a way to avoid that to? Do we want to?

Answer (score 12):

I ran into a similar problem. I need to show the user the result of the POST. I don't want to use sessions and I don't want to redirect with the result in the URL (it's kinda secure, I don't want it accidentally bookmarked). I found a pretty simple solution that should work for the cases mentioned in other answers.

On successfully submitting the form, include this bit of Javascript on the page:

```html
<script>history.pushState({}, "", "")</script>
```

It pushes the current URL onto the history stack. Since this is a new item in history, refreshing won't re-POST.

**UPDATE:** This doesn't work in Safari. It's a known bug. But since it was originally reported in 2017, it may not be fixed soon. I've tried a few things (replaceState, etc), but haven't found a workaround in Safari. Here are some pertinent links regarding the issue:

- [Safari send POST request when refresh after pushState/replaceState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933389/safari-send-post-request-when-refresh-after-pushstate-replacestate)
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202963
- https://github.com/aurelia/history-browser/issues/34

Comment: This one is the perfect answer. I think this should be the best answer.

Comment: This doesn't look like it works with Safari

Comment: @Mav2287 Good catch. I updated the answer with some notes about Safari. Let me know if you find a workaround!

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['uniqid']) AND $_POST['uniqid'] == $_SESSION['uniqid']){
    // can't submit again
}
else{
    // submit!
    $_SESSION['uniqid'] = $_POST['uniqid'];
}
?>

<form action="page.php" method="post" name="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="uniqid" value="<?php echo uniqid();?>" />
    <!-- the rest of the fields here -->
</form>
```

Comment: Is all of the post data added to the session?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is simpler,

**page.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        ... operation on database, like to insert $_POST['name'] in a table ...
        $_SESSION["message"]="Operation Done";
        header("Location:page.php");
        exit;
    }
?>

<html>
<body>
<div style='some styles'>
<?php
//message here
echo $_SESSION["message"];
?>
</div>
<form action='page.php' method='post'>
<!--elements-->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for what I needed this is what works.

Based on all of the above solutions this allows me to go from a form to another form, and to the n^ form , all the while preventing the same exact data from being "saved" over and over when a page is refreshed (and the post data from before lingers onto the new page).

Thanks to those who posted their solution which quickly led me to my own.

```
<?php
//Check if there was a post
if ($_POST) {
//Assuming there was a post, was it identical as the last time?
   if (isset($_SESSION['pastData']) AND $_SESSION['pastData'] != $_POST) {
//No, Save
   } else {
//Yes, Don't save
   }
} else {
//Save
}
//Set the session to the most current post.
$_session['pastData'] = $_POST;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

We work on web apps where we design number of php forms. It is heck to write another page to get the data and submit it for each and every form. To avoid re-submission, in every table we created a 'random_check' field which is marked as 'Unique'.

On page loading generate a random value and store it in a text field (which is obviously hidden).

On SUBMIT save this random text value in 'random_check' field in your table. In case of re-submission query will through error because it can't insert the duplicate value.

After that you can display the error like

```
if ( !$result ) {
        die( '<script>alertify.alert("Error while saving data OR you are resubmitting the form.");</script>' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to redirect...

replace `die();` with

```
isset(! $_POST['name']);
```

, setting the isset to isset not equal to $_POST['name'], so when you refresh it, it would not add anymore to your database, unless you click the submit button again.

```
<?
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        ... operation on database, like to insert $_POST['name'] in a table ...
        echo "Operation Done";
        isset(! $_POST['name']);
    }

?>

<form action='page.php' method='post' name="myForm">
    <input type="text" maxlength="50" name="name" class="input400" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Please be sure in the future to properly format your answers to help other readers ! (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

This happen because of simply on refresh it will submit your request again.

So the idea to solve this issue by cure its root of cause.

I mean we can set up one session variable inside the form and check it when update.

```
if($_SESSION["csrf_token"] == $_POST['csrf_token'] )
{
// submit data  
}

//inside from 

$_SESSION["csrf_token"] = md5(rand(0,10000000)).time(); 

<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value=" 
htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["csrf_token"]);">
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript code presented in the following answer may not necessarily work, even in present day advanced browser.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656609/6337701

The other option to use PHP header `header('Location: /path/to/record')`, doesn't work if u have to display any HTML before the header

The simple way I implemented it is to have at least 1 table field value as MANDATORY (NOT NULL).
During form submission, before INSERT that variable ($VAR1) holding value for that (at least one) mandatory field will be populated. There is a (`if $VAR1==''`) check implemented before insert.

After successful form submission & insert `(if ($connn->query($insertssql) === TRUE)`, I set that `$VAR1 to blank or null`.

So now, when anyone refreshes that submitted webpage, it simply gets a blank value for $VAR1, and the  (`if $VAR1==''`) check does its job to show the error message, and the duplicate insert never happens.

Pseudo code:

```
if ($VAR1=='')
{ echo "Either u refreshed the already submitted form, or mandatory value is missing."; exit;}
else
{//proceed with insert}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think following is the better way to avoid resubmit or refresh the page.

```
$sample = $_POST['submit'];
if ($sample == "true") 
 {
//do it your code here
$sample = "false";
 }
```

Comment: Please explain further, as we know the $sample will be true again on page refresh.