# unable to upload a file through database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to upload a file path into MySQL database.
I have this html form:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="add_maps" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" align="center" dir="rtl">
<tr>
<th>
name of map</th>
<td>
<input type="text" name="name_of_map"/>
</td>
<th>
select map</th>
<td>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<input type="submit" name="submit_map" value="upload"/>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And in the same page, I have the PHP code to upload:

```
<?php
require_once('../include/inner_global.php');
$hostdb = "localhost";
$namedb = "architect";
$userdb = "root";
$passdb = "root";
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$name='';
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");

$path = "../uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
if(isset($_POST['submit_map'])){
    try{
        $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
        $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path)){
            $path = "./uploads/".$path;
            $sql = "INSERT INTO maps(name_of_maps, projects_id, map) VALUES (:name, :id, :file)";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(":name", $name);
            $stmt->bindValue(":id", $id);
            $stmt->bindValue(":file", $path);
            $count = $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        header("location: insert_map_false.php?id=".$id);
    }
}
?>
```

When I go to the page where this html form is, I get directly this error in the header:

[image]

**P.S**

Files are uploaded correctly to their path, when i click on upload, but not added to database.
**EDIT**

This is my table datatypes

[image]

Comment: What is your database type of that field?

Comment: show us the full page code because if you get an error on the page where the html form is, there must be a problem on this page (even before uploading)

Comment: try doing var_dump($_FILES)  in try block to see if your file is uploading.

Comment: guys this is all my html code, and the php code is in the same page

Comment: See the edit section to see my table datatypes

Comment: i think problem in **$id = $_REQUEST['id'];** because value of **$id**
is empty after from submit @am90

Comment: I think @ Rahautos and @droidnation found my errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check from post or not. Add all of your code inside this condition, it will solve your problem:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
//All code ....
}
```

or create `hidden input` inside from:

```
<input type="text" name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['id']; ?>"/>
```

I think the problem is in `$id = $_REQUEST['id'];` because value of `$id` is `empty` after from `submit`

Comment: why your code, removed my error ? what is the difference between $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] and $_POST, and why $_POST didn't removed this error ?

Comment: both are working same in your case but your **$_FILES['file']['name']** is outside of your if condition @am90

Comment: but why when I refresh the page the same file is added again ?

Comment: Unset $_POST after inserting it to Database. **unset($_POST);** @am90

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690541/best-way-to-avoid-the-submit-due-to-a-refresh-of-the-page

Answer (score 1):

Your sql query is:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO maps(name_of_maps, projects_id, map) VALUES (:name, :id, :file)";
```

But your column is `name_of_map` and not `name_of_maps`

You query should be like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO maps(name_of_map, projects_id, map) VALUES (:name, :id, :file)";
```