# Safari send POST request when refresh after pushState/replaceState

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, html5-history, http-method

After post a form, I use pushState/replaceState to manipulate the history. Then when refresh, Chrome will send GET request to the new url, but Safari will send POST. Is it a BUG in Safafi? Anyone had met it before?

Comment: i got the same issue, any updates?

Comment: fyi, I logged a ticket. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202963