# What is the correct specification for reloading after rewriting using window.history.replaceState on a page after a POST transition?

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-history

First, see the differences between browsers below.

- [Google Chrome](https://github.com/Himenon/history_pushState-reload-bugs#google-chrome)
- [Firefox](https://github.com/Himenon/history_pushState-reload-bugs#firefox)
- [Safari](https://github.com/Himenon/history_pushState-reload-bugs#safari)

Two types of POST destination endpoints `/register` and `/register-history-push-state` are provided, but the essential difference is whether or not the following JavaScript is executed.

| `/register` | `/register-history-push-state` |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

```js
window.history.replaceState("", "", "/register-history-push-state");
```

If you reload the page after the POST transition, you will see that the HTTP Method on reload is different, as follows

|  | Reload HTTP Method(NOT exec replaceState) | Reload HTTP Method(exec replaceState) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chrome | `POST` | `GET` |
| Firefox | `POST` | `GET` |
| Safari | `POST` | `POST` |

The specification of [url and history update steps](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#url-and-history-update-steps) does not clearly state here Not found.

Which pattern of behaviour is the correct browser specification?

Comment: Related Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933389/safari-send-post-request-when-refresh-after-pushstate-replacestate

Comment: Webkit Bugzilla: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202963