# How to make a html button target a specific array index in php?

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, post, foreach

I am working on a **html/php** code as shown below. In it **on click of a button from html code, it goes inside foreach block at Line#B in php**.

```
<?php 
     $mp4_files = array_values($mp4_files); 
     print_r($mp4_files);  // Line #A
     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {       
     foreach ($mp4_files as $f)  // Line#B
     { 
            // conversion of mp4 into mp3 is happening, not pasting the full code. 
     }
    }
?> 

<form action="" method="POST">
 <table>
       <tr>
          <th>MP4 Name</th>
          <th>Action</th>
       </tr>
      <?php
        $mp4_files = array_values($mp4_files);
        foreach ($programs as $key => $program)  { 
       $file = $mp4_files[$key];     
       print_r($file);   // Line#B
       ?> 
       <tr>
          <td><?php echo basename($file); ?></td>
          <td><button type="submit" name="go-button" value="Go">Go</button</td>
       </tr>
   <?php } ?>
</table>
</form>
```

The above html/php code display the following content:

[image]

In the screenshot above, we have list of mp4 files with their respective buttons.

**Line#A prints the following array from the html/php code above**:

```
Array ( [0] => 36031P.mp4 [1] => hello.mp4 )
```

**And Line#B:**

```
36031P.mp4 hello.mp4
```

At this moment, on click of a Go button from any table row, **conversion of all mp4 files into mp3 start happening** (which is not my requirement)

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the html/php code above so that if I click on **Go button** from **1st row** above in the screenshot, conversion of **1st row** mp4 file into mp3 should start happening and vice-versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data-tags to achieve this (code is just example demonstrating point):

> PHP / HTML

```
<?php foreach ($files as $key => $file) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="file-name" data-id="<?php echo $key; ?>">
                <?php echo basename($file); ?>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit"
                    class="go-btn"
                    name="go-button"
                    value="Go"
                    data-id="<?php echo $key; ?>"  >
                Go
            </button
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

> JavaScript (jQuery)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $('.go-btn').click(function(e)
    {
        //pass in e(vent) to prevent the default behaviour of type="submit"
        e.preventDefault();

        let target = $(this).attr('data-id'),
            spanEl = $('.file-name[data-id='+ target +']');
        //do whatever with the spanEl - e.g. .text() to get value

        //send the file / ID - depending on how you're retrieving these files
        $.ajax({
            data: {key: 'value'}, //change to what you want
            type: 'post',
            url: '/path/to/script.php',
            success: function(res)
            {
                alert(res)
            },
            error: function(res)
            {
                //log the response for debugging
                console.log(res);

                //tell the user it failed
                alert('The dark elves have been here.. they broke it!')
            }
        })
    })
});
```

> script.php

```
<?php
    # worth nothing that if you're posting a file (with intention of using $_FILES)
    # that you need to change your ajax, add `processData: false, contentType: false, cache: false`
    # and add `enctype="multimedia/form-data"` as an attribute to your form
    $value = $_POST['key']; # key: = index name

    # run conversion on the file
    # here we can add a success/error msg
    echo ($success ? 'It converted!' : 'Conversion failed');
```

By the end of this, you should have a file structure similar to (or at least I'd do it this way):

```
Project_Root
----app
--------convert.php
----index.php
----pub
--------js
------------main.js
```

Answer (score 0):

A dirty way to do this would be to add a name attribute to each button with the respective filename of the file you want that button attached to. When you post, you will receive an array key with the filename of the file that should be converted.  You would just have to loop over your array of MP4's to get a match on the key.

Probably a better way to do this though is to break out each filename/button into its own mini-form, create a hidden field in each form with the value set to the filename that should be converted.

that way when you post, you will have the name of the file that should be converted attached to a key you would already know the name of

Answer (score 0):

Do this Using an Ajax Request

create javascript function convert_video at the bottom of your html file

```
function convert_video(video_id){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'server.com/converttomp3.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {video_id:video_id},
        beforeSend: function(){
            //
        },
        success: function(data)
        {

            var crude = JSON.parse(data);

            if(crude.status){
                alert('Success message');
                window.location.href = window.location.href;
            } else {

                alert(crude.message);
            }


        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //Error

        }
```

Then from the HTML as your Looping Videos

```
<td><button type="submit" onclick="return convert_video('<?php echo $array['video_id'] ;')" name="go-button" value="Go">Go</button</td>
```

finally in your serverside code

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{    
  $video_id = $_POST['video'];
  // processs your video here .
 }
```

Comment: don't forget to remove the action from the <form> tag

Comment: Looking into it. Will keep you posted.

Comment: After processing also you will need to `print  json_encode($objectWithStatus&Message)` response with status and message to notify the user if it was successful or not

Comment: What do you want me to put inside ?

`beforeSend: function(){
            //
        },`

Comment: You can start animating the Go button to show the user that processing has started

Comment: I am getting an error in the `error` section of the AJAX Request in the `function convert_video` `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. I am looking into it whats the issue.

Comment: its a mismatch of quotes make sure it is well arranged eg `convert_video('<?php echo $array["video_id"] ;')"`

Comment: I placed a closing tag of php `onclick="return convert_video('<?php echo $array['video_id'] ;?>')"`

Comment: put double quotes in "video_id"

Comment: I am sending you my script. I am getting some weird errors. https://jsfiddle.net/876qawhu/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194551/discussion-between-stevebaros-and-flash).

Comment: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{    
  $video_id = $_POST['video'];
  // processs your video here .
 }` Is $_POST['video'] should be `$_POST['video_id'];` ?